# Transfer function in MATLAB/Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to model a transfer function block for say 1/(s+1). What is the easiest way to implement a block for a transfer function in Simulink?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for: [Transfer Fcn Block](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/transferfcn.html)

With regard to internet documentation for Simulink, this [Block Reference list](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/f4-4889.html) is a good link to keep on hand.